# How to remove items from IQueryable anonymous type

Tags: c#, asp.net, lambda, iqueryable

```
           var flowers = from f in c.Product
                              select new
                              {
                                  f.ProductID,
                                  f.Price,
                                  f.Name,
                                  f.Description
                              };
                List<int> IDsToRemove = new List<int>();

                foreach(var newRow in flowers)
                {
                    if (((List<int>)Session["UsedIDs"]).Contains(newRow.ProductID))
                    {
                        IDsToRemove.Add(newRow.ProductID);
                    }
                }
```

I've gotten the id's that I want to remove where there is a match between the usedIDs and the productIDs from the query, so I've put all the matching ints into a list of IDsToRemove. Now I don't know how to do something like:

```
     foreach(var id in IDsToRemove){
         flowers.remove(id) }

     ddlFlowers.DataSource = flowers.ToList();
```

Comment: Instead of removing items, you could do`ddlFlowers.DataSource = flowers.Except(ids).ToList();`

Comment: @caleb i've edited my answer

Comment: Alternatively, `flowers.RemoveAll(f => ids.Contains(f));` will remove the items in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var listInSession = (List<int>)Session["UsedIDs"]);
ddlFlowers.DataSource = flowers.Where(f => !listInSession.Contains(f.ProductID)).ToList();
```